# Laravel 8 Blade: Loop through Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, foreach

Wassup Guys,

I am currently working on a project with Google Speech to Text Api.

However, I am sending data from my controller to my .blade.php in this schmema:

```
array:3 [▼
  "transcript" => "I am using a tool to transcribe this audio file"
  "confidence" => 0.94845759868622
  "wordMetaData" => array:3 [▼
    "word" => array:10 [▼
      0 => "I"
      1 => "am"
      2 => "using"
      3 => "a"
      4 => "tool"
      5 => "to"
      6 => "transcribe"
      7 => "this"
      8 => "audio"
      9 => "file"
    ]
    "startTime" => array:10 [▼
      0 => ""0s""
      1 => ""0.200s""
      2 => ""0.500s""
      3 => ""0.800s""
      4 => ""0.900s""
      5 => ""1.300s""
      6 => ""1.500s""
      7 => ""2s""
      8 => ""2.300s""
      9 => ""2.800s""
    ]
    "endTime" => array:10 [▼
      0 => ""0.200s""
      1 => ""0.500s""
      2 => ""0.800s""
      3 => ""0.900s""
      4 => ""1.300s""
      5 => ""1.500s""
      6 => ""2s""
      7 => ""2.300s""
      8 => ""2.800s""
      9 => ""3.300s""
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to use the transcript, the used words and its timings as the confidence in my blade view in a table.

I know that this is possible through @foreach, but I didn't manage to use it properly.

This is my attempt:
Cannot access offset of type string on string (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

```
$apiData['transcript'] = $transcript;
                $apiData['confidence'] = $confidence;
                $apiData['wordMetaData'] = $word;
```

```
 @foreach($apiData as $key => $transcript)
            <div class="notification">
                <button class="delete" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"></button>
                <h1>{{$key}}</h1>
                @foreach($apiData as $key => $confidence)
                <p>{{$key}}</p>
                @foreach ($apiData as $key => $wordMetaData)
                {{ $wordMetaData['word'] }}
                {{ $wordMetaData['startTime'] }}
                {{ $wordMetaData['startTime'] }}
                {{ $wordMetaData['endTime'] }}
            </div>

                @endforeach
                @endforeach
                @endforeach
```

How should I proceed?

[image: json]

Comment: Append to the question the part about: `I didn't manage to use it properly.` You can also see a basic foreach use [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops), and other example usage if you `ctrl+f` search the page for `foreach`.

Comment: This is for strings and Objects but not arrays

Comment: Ok, but it's very similar handling as PHP, then see [this info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), as foreach works on objects and arrays. I still say append to the question the part about: `I didn't manage to use it properly.`, so that we can see WHY the usage may not have been proper.

Comment: Well, how do you wish to use the data? What is the frontend structure?

Comment: @PaulT. I added my attempt

Comment: @nice_dev Check the style inside post